# Visual Basic Regular Expression Question

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a list of string. When user inputs chars in, the program would display all possible strings from the list in a textbox.

```
Dim fruit as new List(Of String) 'contains apple,orange,pear,banana
Dim rx as New Regex(fruit)
```

For example If user enters *a,p,l,e,r* , then the program would display apple and pear. **It should match any entry for which all letters have been entered, regardless of order and regardless of additional letters.**
What should I add to rx? If it's not possible with Regular Expressions, then please specify any other ways to do this.

Comment: Why do apple and pear appear and not the others?

Comment: Is the order of the input characters relevant? E.g. `a,p,l` matches `apple` but `p,l,a` does not? And: should `pear` really match in your example? Because there is a `l` in your character list.

Comment: Because user didn't entered o,n,g for orange and b,n for banana. The idea is to display all words, which chars have been entered.

Comment: But a is in orange, and l is not in pear. So why does pear match and orange not?

Comment: @Andrew: Sounds like it should match any entry for which all distinct letters have been entered, regardless of order and regardless of additional letters.

Comment: @David Yes! That's just what I want. So are there any solutions?

Comment: @Andrew: It looks like the rule is that a match indicates that all letters of a word appear in the list. Of `a,p,l,e,r` only apple and pear can be spelled completely with those letters.

Comment: @Cobold: With a regex?  I'm not sure.  I'm very interested to see such a regex for something like this.  If I had to do it right now I'd probably start with a fairly slow looping-through-characters construct.

Comment: @David I saw that Regex in Python. It was like (fruit + '$',)

Comment: @David, @Cobold regex approach added to my response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**LINQ Approach:**

```
Dim fruits As New List(Of String) From { "apple", "orange", "pear", "banana" }
Dim input As String = "a,p,l,e,r"
Dim letters As String = input.Replace(",", "")
Dim result = fruits.Where(Function(fruit) Not fruit.Except(letters).Any())
```

**Regex Approach:**

A regex pattern to match the results would resemble something like:

```
"^[apler]+$"
```

This can be built up as:

```
Dim fruits As New List(Of String) From { "apple", "orange", "pear", "banana" }
Dim input As String = "n,a,b,r,o,n,g,e"
Dim letters As String = input.Replace(",", "")
Dim pattern As String = "^[" + letters + "]+$"
Dim query = fruits.Where(Function(fruit) Regex.IsMatch(fruit, pattern))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail for pear? Also, it seems to me that it would return any word that contained `a,p,l,e` but also contained other letters - like `maple`.

Comment: @Joel your comment is correct. I missed the clarification in the OP's comments.

Comment: @Joel check out the update approach. It should now take those issues into account.

Comment: How can I display the results in a textbox?

Comment: @Cobold you need to loop over the results and append them to the textbox... or if you want to display them as a comma separated list of items you could use `Dim text As String = String.Join(", ", result)`

Comment: @Cobold regex approach added to my response.

Comment: @Ahmad: The regex approach was how I was ultimately looking at it. Had a meeting to go to so I wasn't able to answer with it though :)

Comment: @Joel always a dilemma when trying to squeeze in an answer before meetings! :)